# A question about word order

Tags: differences

Which of the following sentences is natural and common in terms of word order?

"This picture was taken by my uncle last year."

"This picture was taken last year by my uncle."

In English sentences, does the last part of a sentence, such as "by my uncle" in the second sentence, get focal emphasis?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first is more natural but neither is incorrect. You are correct that the last part of the sentence gets greater emphasis.

Comment: (a) both are natural and common in terms of word order. (b) in English sentences, the focal positions are the beginning and the end. There are dozens of syntactic rules that move constituents to or from these positions for emphasis or de-emphasis. So in these sentences the focus is on when it was taken for the first one, and on who it was taken by for the second one.

Answer (score -1):

These sentences are both correct. However,  it depends on the speaker to determine which is more correct. The speaker chooses which points he wants to emphasize. Whether he wants to emphasize who took the picture,  or when it was taken.